# Don't allow consecutive same character and some different character together in TextFormField

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I want to restrict the TextFormField to only accept numbers separated by commas and sometimes with dashes but I don't want them to come consecutive to each other and also don't want the same character consecutive.

Ex:-

- `1,3-4,9-11` is correct
- `1,,3--4,9-11` is wrong
- `1,-3-4,9-11` is wrong
- `1-,3-4,9-11` is wrong

To restrict things to only numbers, commas and dashes I'm using:-

```dart
FilteringTextInputFormatter(
   RegExp("[0-9,-]"),
   allow: true
)
```

But it is not restricting the consecutive behavior as shown in the wrong behavior in the examples.

So, how can I restrict my TextFormField to the correct behavior represented in the examples?

Thank you.

Update: I finally followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73954311/15199864) approach for this problem.

Comment: Use a validator on submit to reject bad strings.  Do *not* attempt to do this with a Filter... it's problematic at best.

Comment: Oh thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I guess then the only option I have is validating on submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to validate on submit, you might write the pattern as:

```
^[0-9]+(?:[,-][0-9]+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ESeLQj/1)

If a negative lookahead is supported, you an exclude matching 2 times one of `-` or `,` while validating on typing.

Note that this will allow `,` or `-` at the end:

```
^(?!.*[,-][,-])[0-9,-]*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Whwscg/1)

Comment: You can't use that as a filtering pattern, because you'll never be able to enter 3, on your way to 3,4.  That's the problem with using a Filter for this. You need it to be a validator on submit only.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz If it works like that, this will indeed only work on validating the whole string at submit.

Comment: Hey, thank you. The second one worked perfectly but as soon as I try to enter the wrong pattern my TextField automatically gets cleared. Can I avoid that? Removing the $ from the first one stops the clearing but I don't know what to remove from the second one to stop the clearing.

Comment: @Deepanshu Perhaps like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69510015/flutter-textfield-regex-clears-text-input

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes but for the second one more related is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71537292/textformfield-clears-input-text-even-if-the-regex-expression-is-satisfied . Reading the comments in it my only option is validation to avoid clearing text. I will still accept your answer because the regex mentioned by you is correct and working.

Answer (score 0):

For my problem above I finally combined FilteringTextInputFormatter with a custom TextInputFormatter specific to my case so I'm adding it below so that if anyone wants to do the same they can have a look at this approach:

```dart
class RangeTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
    TextEditingValue oldValue,
    TextEditingValue newValue,
  ) {
    TextSelection newSelection = newValue.selection;
    String truncated = newValue.text;

    int oldValueLength = oldValue.text.length;
    int newValueLength = newValue.text.length;

    // Blocks comma and dash at start.
    if ((oldValue.text.isEmpty || oldValue.text == "") &&
        (newValue.text[newValueLength - 1] == "," ||
            newValue.text[newValueLength - 1] == "-")) {
      truncated = oldValue.text;
      newSelection = oldValue.selection;
    }
    // Allows numbers at start.
    else if (oldValue.text.isEmpty || oldValue.text == "") {
      truncated = newValue.text;
      newSelection = newValue.selection;
    } else {
      // Blocks comma and dash after comma.
      if (oldValue.text[oldValueLength - 1] == "," &&
          (newValue.text[newValueLength - 1] == "," ||
              newValue.text[newValueLength - 1] == "-")) {
        truncated = oldValue.text;
        newSelection = oldValue.selection;
      }
      // Blocks comma and dash after dash.
      else if (oldValue.text[oldValueLength - 1] == "-" &&
          (newValue.text[newValueLength - 1] == "," ||
              newValue.text[newValueLength - 1] == "-")) {
        truncated = oldValue.text;
        newSelection = oldValue.selection;
      }
      // Blocks dash after number dash number. Ex: 48-58- <- this last dash is blocked
      else if (oldValue.text.lastIndexOf('-') != -1) {
        if (!(oldValue.text
                .substring(oldValue.text.lastIndexOf('-'))
                .contains(",")) &&
            newValue.text[newValueLength - 1] == "-") {
          truncated = oldValue.text;
          newSelection = oldValue.selection;
        }
      }
    }

    return TextEditingValue(
      text: truncated,
      selection: newSelection,
      composing: TextRange.empty,
    );
  }
}
```

Now use it just like `FilteringTextInputFormatter`:

```dart
inputFormatters: [
      FilteringTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[0-9,-]"), allow: true),
      RangeTextInputFormatter(),
]
```